Wind and Ocean Currents Don't Match
I have been following Artifexian's tutorials and ran into a snag when plotting wind and ocean currents. My planet is retrograde, so I know that the currents need to flow opposite that of earth's. When plotting my ocean currents, everything looked good, however the problem occurred when I placed my high-pressure zones and their direction. The top hemisphere is correct in that all the currents align with each other. In the bottom hemisphere though the currents don't match. I have double and triple checked my work but can't see where I went wrong. I have attached a picture of my world with both ocean and wind currents.

Given a retrograde planet, where are my mistakes in my currents and how do I fix them?

I can't speak to Artifexian's tutorial, I've never used it, but when you look at maps of Earth's oceanic currents and wind patterns, wind patterns generally follow oceanic currents. I'll speak more to this below. First, some maps:
SEOS-Project.eu
FOXWeather.com
The simple explanation is that everything on your planet is reversed compared to Earth. But let's stop a moment and explain that in greater detail.
Cool water and cool air both basically react the same way. On a water world (0% landmass) you'd have a unified current and trade wind at the equator that's pushed by the rising sun — the trade winds and equatorial currents shown in the maps above. This means the current and trade winds at the equator flow retrograde to the planet's rotation.
Thanks to the spherical shape of the planet, water and air at the poles are always cooler than water and air at the equator, which means you'd constantly have water and air "peeling away" toward the lower pressure poles. This causes the prograde circumpolar currents and winds — the prevailing westerlies and antarctic circumpolar current shown in the maps above. (An arctic circumpolar current exists, but it's much more complex due to the lack of a convenient north polar landmass.)
I'm sure I'm not using retrograde and prograde the way astronomers would. I pray for their forgiveness as I'm trying to use the words as referents.
Complexity happens when you add landmasses. Landmass affects currents (which can't push past landmass) much more than it affects wind (which can push over the top of landmass). But it's the pressure of the proverbial rising sun that's creating "effect #1" when it comes to currents and wind.
Now think about placing your high pressure zones.
